# View.post() method

Tags: android, view

I don't understand how to use View.post() method and when to use it like below, I just know it runs in UIThread, so why should I use it?

```
swipeRefreshLayout.post(newRunnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you using it then ?

Answer (score 2):

When your in a worker thread/ separate thread (other than UI thread) at that time if you access the UI elements like buttons or views it will throw exception. So in this situation to update UI elements we have to use `View.post()` method